# Llamar a metodo cada cierto tiempo

Tags: angularjs

Mi app.js

```
$scope.leerProductos = function() {

  InitService.leerProductos().then(
         function(d) {
           $scope.productos = d;
            }
        );
};
```

Mi html :

```
<div ng-init="leerProductos()">
  <div ng-repeat="pro in productos">
        {{pro.name}} y {{pro.precio}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Como puedo hacer para que llame a ese método cada 5 segundos?

Comment: Hola SirDaiz, te faltaría añadir el codigo de lo que **has intentado** y por qué no te funciona o qué problemas te surjen. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b el codigo que digo solo llama una vez y necesito que sea llamado cada 5 segundos

Comment: ya, pero qué has intentado para que se llame cada X segundos?

Comment: acabo de probar el codigo que me a dicho @Maghdiel Campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo soluciones asi:

```
$scope.leerProductos = function() {


var promise = $interval(function()    { 
    InitService.leerProductos().then(
      function(d) {
        $scope.productos = d;
    }
                );
        }, 
 5000);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function ()   { 
   $interval.cancel(promise); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto te servirá, en el enlace hay un ejemplo de lo que necesitas, [Link de refencia](https://www.uno-de-piera.com/interval-en-angularjs/)

```
$scope.leerProductos = function() {
    InitService.leerProductos().then(
        function(d) {
            $scope.productos = d;
        }
    );

    var promise = $interval(function() 
    { 
        //Aqui es cuando llama tu función
        $scope.leerProductos();
    }, 
    5000);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () 
    { 
        $interval.cancel(promise); 
    });
};
```

Comment: tengo un modal con ng-init, he probado tu codigo y llama cada 5 segundos, el problema que cuando cierro el modal sigue llamando y me dejo bloqueado el navegador, segun el ejemplo cuando cambie de url ya no llamará, pero quiero que cuando le de a cerrar al modal pare

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado, no pude seguir contestándote por que este chrome se come la memoria jaja y no me dejaba abrirlo, cualquier duda me avisas.